# Android 'onConfigurationChanged' event not getting fired

Tags: android, orientation, android-orientation

Is it that when we call `setRequestedOrientation` from then function `onConfigurationChanged` then after `onConfigurationChanged` never gets called?

As i have read somewhere that when we call `setRequestedOrientation` function from the activity then function `onConfigurationChanged` never gets called.

I am in dead block now, no way to go.

I have my activity which i need to display in portrait mode only, but when user plays the video in the video view and then after when user changes the orientation to landscape then i need to make the activity+video in the landscape.

Problem is that when i call `setRequestedOrientation` method to set the application orientation to portrait then after method `onConfigurationChanged` never gets called.

And when i remove the call `setRequestedOrientation` then when video is not running my and when user changes the orientation then my activity also changes the orientation which i can't control.

Comment: I think that's true, to handle this. first include this into the `AndroidManifest` - > `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`. Take a look here too - > http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration)

Comment: Yes i have added this line in the manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

Do it to get device orientation by sensor again.

```
setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `setRequestedOrientation` call is to force your activity to remain in the given orientation, so you can lock it to portrait for example. This is why `onConfigurationChanged` doesn't get called.

If you want to rotate the app then you can specify different layout XML files for each orientation or get the orientation of the app and deal with it programatically.

See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setRequestedOrientation(int)

And here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#orientation

Comment: I have tried above mentioned methods to get the device orientation but when we set the device orientation using "setRequestedOrientation" then all these functions returns same values every time. so is there any of of getting the orientation of the device after we call "setRequestedOrientation" method. i am not able to find this.

Comment: Using setRequestedOrientation will lock the app to that orientation and not allow it to rotate. If you want the app to rotate, do no call setRequestedOrientation.

Comment: There are two things i want archive, app to be of fixed orientation when no video is running so calling `setRequestedOrientation` but second thing when video is running i want to know the current orientation (which i am not able to get at all), if device in landscape then i want to change the orientation of the activity to landscape.

Comment: What most apps do there is just force it. Once you start a video playing most media apps just rotate the screen to landscape and force the user that way.